# Hiding div on specific page with jquery not functioning on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I want my canvas (chain from [paper.js](http://paperjs.org/examples/chain/)) hidden, but only on a specific page, to allow  the touch scroll on mobile devices when it is necessary. Because of that Media queries was not the solution, so I used a jquery script only linked with my page to hide my .canvas div :

```
if ($(window).width() < 640) {
$('.canvas').hide();
} else {
$('.canvas').show();
}
```

It works "perfectly" when resizing and reloading the window in firefox, safari and chrome… But on mobile devices the canvas is not hiden. Any idea ?

By the way I used the [Stacey lightweight CMS](http://www.staceyapp.com/) and make sure that my script :

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].className += ' js-enabled';
</script>
```

was in my html doc. I don't even know if it is useful but I tried…

Comment: Mobile devices come in many sizes - some as big or bigger than desktop/laptop devices -- so what sizes are you looking at? Is the viewport in portrait and landscape less than 640px, have tried less than or equal to <= and does the device(s) you're viewing this on accurately report their pixels. Since you don't want to interfere with touch this is not the solution since touch devices are larger than this too. May want to actually detect touch https://github.com/izilla/Supports-Touch

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using media queries, which is supported on all browsers and almost all mobile browsers, here is an example:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 640) {
    .canvas { display: none; }
}
```

Add this to your CSS and it should fix it.

Comment: That was my first idea but it would hide my canvas on my all site when I want it hidden on one specific page… Anyway thanks for the answer

Comment: @VictorLebeau Why not make a specific CSS file for that page or add it in the page using <style></style> tags?

Comment: Probably the easiest and best idea ! Is it possible to add a media queries directly in the html using 
    <style="@media queries {
.canvas{
display:none;
}
}">

Comment: Directly in the HTML you need to use: <style> .canvas {display:none;} </style>

Answer (score 0):

some mobile browsers do not support javascript, if this is the case you're better off using a  tag just to alert the mobile user they can't view the change because their browser doesn't support javascript